# xampp php email (gmail) doesnt work

Tags: php, email, gmail, xampp

- I have been trying to send email with php using xampp (i am using windows 8.1)
- i just cant get it right
- tried smtp_port= 465/ 587/ 25
- i have enabled gmail using IMAP
- from the debug.log, i think i connected to google

is there any other way i can test my code. i want to send email using php with an url in the email.

sendemail.ini

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587

error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=xxxxxxx@gmail.com
auth_password=xxxxxxxx
```

the php.ini

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = xxxxxxx@gmail.com

sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

mail.add_x_header=Off
```

the php i use

```
<?php

$subject = "Simple mail";
$message = "Here is a test mail";
$to = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$from = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$header = "From: ".$from;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){
   print "success<br>";
}else{
   print "fail<br>";}
?>
```

things i find in debug.log

```
14/04/19 04:42:11 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
14/04/19 04:42:11 ** To: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
14/04/19 04:42:11 ** Subject: Simple mail
14/04/19 04:42:11 ** From: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
14/04/19 04:42:11 ** 
14/04/19 04:42:11 ** Here is a test mail
14/04/19 04:42:11 ** --- MESSAGE END ---
14/04/19 04:42:12 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
14/04/19 04:42:12 ** Connected.
14/04/19 04:42:12 << 220 mx.google.com ESMTP ac5sm61735964pbc.37 - gsmtp<EOL>
14/04/19 04:42:12 >> EHLO C-PC<EOL>
14/04/19 04:42:12 << 250-mx.google.com at your service, [1.64.44.192]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250 CHUNKING<EOL>
14/04/19 04:42:12 ** Authenticating as xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
14/04/19 04:42:12 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
14/04/19 04:42:13 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
14/04/19 04:42:13 >> QUIT<EOL>
14/04/19 04:42:13 << <--some random code here, cannot be copied-->

14/04/19 04:42:13 << <--some random code here again, cannot be copied-->
14/04/19 04:42:13 ** Disconnected.
14/04/19 04:42:13 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
14/04/19 04:42:13 ** Disconnected.
14/04/19 04:42:13 ** Disconnected.
14/04/19 04:42:13 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

is it windows 8.1 or am i missing some??? i spend nearly a day trying to fix this.
     keep getting fail in the php!

Comment: There is some probability that your ISP blocks outgoing emails. My ISP blocks outgoing email sent out from their IP address to avoid spam. perhaps your ISP is doing it also. http://www.authsmtp.com/faqs/faq-4.html

Comment: thx for your information. is there any other way i can test my code. i want to send email using php with an url in the email.

Comment: Are you using a dynamic IP address? If you're using a static IP address, have you set the server hostname and address?

Comment: im using dynamic IP address, wt do i need to do??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: wt is "file_get_contents('contents.html');" >.<